# Importing Openlayers ES2015 modules into angular-cli project

Tags: angular, openlayers, openlayers-3, angular-cli

Hy,

I'm having trouble importing the new [openlayers ES2015 modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ol/) into a angular project build using angular-cli.

I had openlayers as global dependency in my angular-cli.json until now and everything worked fine, but now I would like to switch due to the size of openlayers and only the small part I'm actually using.

What I have done is, remove all the reference to the current openlayers installation, and installed ol using `npm install --save ol`. Then when trying to import the Map module in a component as `import { Map } from 'ol/map';` the build/serve process throws the error: `Cannot find module 'ol/map'`

I'm pretty new to webpack and co and therefore hoped to get a easy start with angular-cli. I'm using angular-cli beta 31.

Can anyone help me please!

Thanks and greetings

Comment: Thats because the package 'ol' does not provide typings for Typescript. There is an open issue for this https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/6496

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it just by changing

```
import { Map } from 'ol/map';
```

to this:

```
import Map from 'ol/map';
```

Hope it works!.